# Kentico v7 - Disable 'GetAzureFile' Permanent url

Tags: kentico

I'm working in a site on Kentico v7 but i have a problem with the images that were stored in media folder; because i was trying to get on CMS the direct URL link of the image in the folder, but the link that CMS displayed is using the page "GetAzureFile.aspx" to get the image; I was validated in SiteManager  -> Content -> Media -> General  that the option "Use Permanent URL" is disabled but the problem appeared again.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using blob storage or an Azure CDN to store your media files?

Comment: The CMS was installed  on a Azure server, and the site that i´m working was imported from a local CMS.

Comment: Is it running in a web farm environment as well or just a single server?  The problem might be that in the web.config the site is setup to use Azure storage and not the local storage.  This is why you'd get the GetAzureFile.aspx option vs. the standard GetFile.aspx reference.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure projects always use blob storage to store newly uploaded files. This is because technically the only files available physically in file system are the ones that were deployed with the project, and when any Azure instance restarts, it looses its local file system and only deployment package is restored on new instances.

As media library content may change on-the-fly, Kentico uses GetAzureFile links for all files to be able to serve them regardless of their storage.

You can however use hardcoded links directly to file system to the files that were part of the deployment package, e.g. ones that you use for site design.